# Auto refresh the div in jquery and php

Tags: jquery

This is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
var pathtopage = window.location.href;
$('#refreshing').load(pathtopage + '#refreshing');
},2000);
</script>
```

When i run the code,i got error like this

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

How to rectify the error

Comment: `load()` should be asynchronous anyway?

Comment: @BenM the default is set to async: true. I have noticed that it has to be explicitly specify.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are doing with window.location.href, but this how you should be doing, where you are calling an end point that returns you something ...   his would do the job.

```
 $(function() {
        start();
    });

    function start() {
        setTimeout(start,2000);
        $.get(pathtopage, function(data) {
            $('#refreshing').html(data);    
        });
    }
```

Comment: I need to refresh every 5 seconds.How can i use setTimeout

Comment: @Nisha.A Please read this for setTimeout explanation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp change 2000 to 5000

Comment: @Nisha.A search more .. this is offtopic how to set endless timeout.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude there is a fundamental difference between interval and timeout. Then write setInterval in $(function() { setInterval(start, 5000) }); once and forget. Don't forget to clear Interval :))

Comment: @Nisha.A It should be just a warning, otherwise, set async to false and see the impact. You will have to replace $.get with $.ajax I think. You could try quickly by typing this command - $.ajaxSetup({async:true}) before you call start(); but it is not recommended as ajax will become sjax :))